# Как реализовать роутинг с неограниченой вложенностью?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Как сделать матчинг на адрес вида: `https://localhost/Страница_с_файлами/Каталог1/Катлог2/..../Каталог17/файл`

Использую `react-router-dom` **v6**, пробовал что-то в таком духе, но работает не так как ожидалось, всегда матчится только каталог

```js
  {
    path: '/:dir/*',
    element: <div>Каталог {:dir}</div>,
    children: [
      {
        path: ':file',
        element: <div>file {:file}</div>,
      },
    ],
  }
```